# How to search text in Microsoft Word (.doc or .docx) files from command line or batch mode?

Tags: shell, batch-file, ms-word, .doc

I need to search some text or phrases in Microsoft Word (.doc and .docx) files under several directories.

I'd like to use command lines or some .bat or .sh file (I can execute on windows or Ubuntu ....).

I've seen that there are some tips on using VBA in Microsoft Word but I'd like another way ......

Are there any tool / library or other things on this issue?

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance!!!

Cesare

Comment: The `FINDSTR` command will work for **.DOC** files but not **.DOCX**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tools but no all have the command line options. This links explain some possibilities : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/25-text-batch-processing-tools-reviewed/

PowerGrep can search in MS-Word files and have a command line option:

> PowerGrep can quickly search text and binary files, compressed
>   archives, MS Word documents, Excel spreadsheets, PDF files, OpenOffice
>   documents, Lotus spreadsheets, Zip files and more on a network and PC.
>   Regular expressions can be used to conveniently specify text to search
>   for. The best part is that you can search for binary data as well as
>   words and phrases. After searching and replacing, you have the option
>   to preview the results without modifying any files. You also benefit
>   from flexible backup and undo options, which are icing on the cake.
>
> PowerGrep runs on Windows 98/ME/NT4/2000/XP/Vista. One other feature I
>   like is being able to save PowerGREP actions and invoke them from the
>   command line to automate recurring tasks. Developers can integrate
>   PowerGREP actions and results with enterprise software through
>   PowerGREP’s open XML file formats.